# How to play local video in shiny app?(Windows)

Tags: r, shiny

I tried the follow code:

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$video(id="video2", type = "video/mp4",src = "sample.mp4", controls = "controls")
  )
)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){})
```

But, it returns a blank page,

[image]

How should I do to play the video?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone late to this question - it won't play in RStudio's 'Run App' environment - launch your app to the browser and it seems to work fine.